# MSR605 Magnetic Card Reader unable to read cards without special software

Tags: magnetic-cards

We have an application that allows a CC Reader (such as the MSR206) to be swiped to enter in a credit card number.

These magnetic swipe readers essentially just dump whatever data is on the card to the screen cursur, as if it was typed.
For example, if you had notepad open, and you swiped a card, then it would output the data into notepad.  There is no programming necessary, except to parse the data, etc.

I recently purchased the MSR605, which can write as well as read cards.  However, I am unable to get it to read info from the cards, unless I have their software open, which sets the card reader to "Read Mode".

Is there a way to utilized a Magnetic Reader/Writer like the MSR605 as a simple reader?

In the MSR Programmers Manual, it states the following:
"1. Power on your system (PC).
2. Setup the usb driver(for windows xp or vista) and Setup the driver for MSR605,all driver in the cd.
3. Connect USB of the MSR605 signal cable to a free serial port .
4. Connect Power-in cable to Power supply and AC receptacle (110V~240V).
5. Now you can use the MSR605 like MSR206."

However, I have not been able to get that to work.  I setup the driver, and it still does not read, unless I open the separate program, and even then, it only reads into the windows in the MSR605.

Answer (score -1):

You need to down load the MSR605 software its a program you can get for free if you go onca web site that sells them it will say software next to what machine you have it won't work with out it

Comment: Thanks.
My question was originally based on a mis-understanding of the capabilities/purpose of the magnetic strip reader that I purchased.  The MSR605 can only be used with additional software (either the software included, or by downloading software), which initiates read mode versus write mode.

If I wanted a mag strip reader that will read input without any additional software to invoke, I needed a reader that doesn't have a writer as well.  Once I purchased said reader, it worked fine.

Comment: @David, actually, they have models of that same reader/writer that now have the drivers built in.  They are also USB and not serial.  With these, they default work as keyboard inputs, but also may perform other actions if you use the API that comes on the cd.